# Why use an immutable reference to i32

Tags: reference, rust, primitive-types

In the chapter Lifetimes of the Rust book, there's an example:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    x: &'a i32,
}

fn main() {
    let y = &5; // this is the same as `let _y = 5; let y = &_y;`
    let f = Foo { x: y };

    println!("{}", f.x);
}
```

Why do they use `x: &'a i32`?

I think if it is just `x: i32` then they cannot demonstrate the lifetime usage. However, is there any other reason behind it? Is there any production code that uses immutable reference to a primitive type like i32?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this particular case the reason is indeed to show the concept of lifetimes. As for the general case, however, I see no reason making an immutable reference to a primitive type (mutable references, of course, is another matter) except of when it is done in generic code:

```
struct Holder<'a, T> {
    r: &'a T
}

let x: i32 = 123;
let h: Holder<i32> = Holder { r: &x };
```

Here if you have such structure, you have no other choice as to use a reference to an `i32`. Naturally, this structure can also be used with other, non-primitive and non-movable types.

As Shepmaster has mentioned in comments, there is indeed a case where you have references to primitive types - it is by-reference iterators. Remember, by a convention (which the standard library follows) `iter()` method on a collection should return an iterator of references into the collection:

```
let v: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let i = v.iter();  // i is Iterator<Item=&i32>
```

Then almost all methods on the iterator which take a closure will accept closures whose argument is a reference:

```
i.map(|n| *n + 1)  // n is of type &i32
```

Note that this is in fact a consequence of the more general case with generics. Vectors and slices may contain arbitrary types, including non-moveable ones, so they just have to have methods which would allow their users to borrow their contents.

Comment: How about using the immutable reference as an observer?

Comment: @zenith an observer of what? You can't mutate the value while there is an outstanding borrow.

Comment: @Shepmaster Oh totally forgot about that. Thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster, can you please give an example of &[i32]? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've updated the answer to expand more on slices. However, I still think this is just a consequence of the case with generics - the reason why slices provide iterators which yield references is because they are generic and can hold arbitrary types, so they need a way to allow the user to borrow their contents.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev absolutely! It's just that the slices and iterator adapters are cases of a reference to a primitive that people will run into in the real world.