# Why do immutable references to copy types in rust exist?

Tags: rust

So I just started learning rust (first few chapters of "the book") and am obviously quite a noob. I finished the ownership-basics chapter (4) and wrote some test programs to make sure I understood everything. I seem to have the basics down but I asked myself why immutable references to copy-types are even possible. I will try to explain my thoughts with examples.

I thought that you maybe want to store a reference to a copy-type so you can check it's value later instead of having a copy of the old value but this can't be it since the underlying value can't be changed as long as it's been borrowed.
The most basic example of this would be this code:

```
let mut x = 10; // push i32
let x_ref = &x; // push immutable reference to x
// x = 100;        change x which is disallowed since it's borrowed currently
println!("{}", x_ref); // do something with the reference since you want the current value of x
```

The only reason for this I can currently think of (with my current knowledge) is that they just exist so you can call generic methods which require references (like `cmp`) with them.
This code demonstrates this:

```
let x = 10;               // push i32
// let ordering = 10.cmp(x); try to compare it but you can't since cmp wants a reference
let ordering = 10.cmp(&x) // this works since it's now a reference
```

So, is that the only reason you can create immutable references to copy-types?

Disclaimer:
I don't see *Just continue reading the book* as a valid answer. However I fully understand if you say something like *Yes you need those for this and this use-case (optional example), it will be covered in chapter X*. I hope you understand what I mean :)

EDIT:
Maybe worth mentioning, I'm a C# programmer and not new to programming itself.

EDIT 2:
I don't know if this is technically a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021676/why-use-an-immutable-reference-to-i32) but I do not fully understand the question and the answer so I hope for a more simple answer understandable by a *real noob*.

Comment: Even if the language designers couldn't think of a use-case at the time, what would be the point of putting a special case in the compiler just to restrict it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I didn't think that. I'm just asking if there are any other reasons/use-cases for this apart from  the one I mentioned.

Comment: Well your question asks why they are even possible. For them not be possible, the compiler would have to have a special exception for them. You might want to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An immutable reference to a `Copy`-type is still "an immutable reference". The code that gets passed the reference can't change the original value. It can make a (hopefully) trivial copy of that value, but it can still only ever change that copy after doing so.

That is, the original owner of the value is ensured that - while receivers of the reference may decide to make a copy and change that - the state of whatever is referenced can't ever change. If the receiver wants to change the value, it can feel free; nobody else is going to see it, though.

Immutable references to primitives are not different, and while being `Copy` everywhere, you are probably more inclined to what "an immutable reference" means semantically for primitive types. For instance

```
fn print_the_age(age: &i32) { ... }
```

That function could make a copy via `*age` and change it. But the caller will not see that change and it does not make much sense to do so in the first place.

---

Update due to comment: There is no advantage per se, at least as far as primitives are concerned (larger types may be costly to copy). It does boil down to the semantic relationship between the owner of the `i32` and the receiver: "Here is a reference, it is guaranteed to not change while you have that reference, I - the owner - can't change or move or deallocate and there is no other thread else including myself that could possibly do that".

Consider where the reference is coming from: If you receive an `&i32`, wherever it is coming from can't change and can't deallocate. The `i32´ may be part of a larger type, which - due to handing out a reference - can't move, change or get de-allocated; the receiver is guaranteed of that. It's hard to say there is an advantage per se in here; it might be advantageous to communicate more detailed type (and lifetime!) relationships this way.

Comment: My question basically boils down to the last part. What's the advantage of using `&i32` instead of `i32` in your `print_the_age` function. Any changes won't be visible outside the function, both go on the stack, .. what else is there? :)

Comment: Okay I think I understand a bit better. However the part about semantic relationship confuses me a bit. _Here's a reference, it won't change and anything you do to it won't affect me_, Wouldn't this also be true for a copy? _Here's a copy, it obviously can't change and you can do anything to it but it won't affect me._ Isn't this almost the same as with a reference? Something which might help me understand, Would you actually use `&i32` in your `print_the_age` function or would you use `i32` in a real world application?

Answer (score 2):

They're very useful, because they can be passed to generic functions that expect a reference:

```
fn map_vec<T, U>(v: &Vec<T>, f: impl Fn(&T) -> U) -> Vec<U> {...}
```

If immutable references of non-`Copy` types were forbidden, we would need two versions:

```
fn map_vec_own<T: !Copy, U>(v: &Vec<T>, f: impl Fn(&T) -> U) -> Vec<U> {...}
fn map_vec_copy<T: Copy, U>(v: &Vec<T>, f: impl Fn( T) -> U) -> Vec<U> {...}
```

Comment: That's the only use-case I could think of as you can see in my question. Are you saying this is indeed the only one?

Answer (score 0):

Immutable references are, naturally, used to provide access to the referenced data. For instance, you could have loaded a dictionary and have multiple threads reading from it at the same time, each using their own immutable reference. Because the references are immutable those threads will not corrupt that common data.

Using only mutable references, you can't be sure of that so you need to make full copies. Copying data takes time and space, which are always limited. The primary question for performance tends to be if your data fits in CPU cache.

I'm guessing you were thinking of "copy" types as ones that fit in the same space as the reference itself, i.e. `sizeof(type) <= sizeof(type*)`. Rust's [Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait indicates data that could be safely copied, no matter the size. These are orthogonal concepts; for instance, a pointer might not be safely copied without adjusting a refernce count, or an array might be copyable but take gigabytes of memory. This is why [`Rc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) has the Clone trait, not Copy.

Comment: I was actually thinking about the copy trait (keep in mind I really don't have much knowledge yet). In my mind, I couldn't find a reason for an immutable reference to a type which will be copied anyway. Why use a reference which can give you a value but the value won't ever change (cannot change a borrowed variable) instead of just copying the value and using that. Both (copied variable and reference) would onto the stack. And assuming integer types, the size would also be simmilar. Does the secret lie in multithreading where the borrowed value could change and you can access it through a ref?

Comment: The Copy trait doesn't mean things *will* be copied, only that they *could*. So it's the small types concept I was guessing about in the third paragraph (come to think of it, likely also some vector types larger than pointers). For small copy types which fit in a register, there's no performance gain in using immutable references, but it's a bit of a pain to specialize functions to have both owned and borrowed data. This is one point where Rust's reference system gets a bit noisy unnecessarily.

Comment: Okay maybe I should have specified just `i32` or `u32` but as far as I understood those are typical copy types so they all behave the same in this case. In the semi-duplicate the answer states "As for the general case, however, I see no reason making an immutable reference to a primitive type except of when it is done in generic code" and they also mention "by-reference iterators" - do you agree with that or is your case with multiple threads also a possible use-case for these kind of references?

Comment: It's a possible use, but when the shared data is that small there's no reason to do it, so it just falls under generic code.